# How to send smaller images to mobile browsers (eliminate large data requests)

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, sprite

When designing a responsive web page, we obviously want images that are larger on larger screens and smaller on smaller screens. It seems like there are many ways to accomplish this so I am wondering,  from a **performance** way, what is the best method.  Here is what I am thinking (but I could be missing something)

- Create a spritesheet with all the images at the maximum size they would be shown, as well as separate sprite sheets for mobile sizes and use media queries to determine which sheet should be requested.  (I do not know if this would work for inline images though)

or

- Just have one size of image and let css resize it based on screen size.  (This seems wasteful because the user would be downloading much larger image files than needed and would then have to scale them down)

I am sure there are alternate methods or issues with what I am proposing so I would appreciate any help on how to structure my image assets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library such as phpmobiledetect to detect if a user is using a mobile device, then you can use some code like this

```
<?php 
if($isMobile){
    echo "<img src='smallImage.png'/>";
}else{
    echo "<img src='bigImage.png'/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah, if only I used php

Comment: If the device is actually a "mobile" device or not doesn't say much about its viewport size and also nothing about its device pixel ratio!

Answer (score 1):

This article contains a great amount of information on this subject. [One Solution To Responsive Images](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/03/one-solution-to-responsive-images/)

The code they provide is similar to your first suggestion, but they give a great example of how to send different images in a single block of code instead of a whole stylesheet.

edit: Removed code I originally posted, I didn't do enough research on the browser support. However, the article should still give you some ideas.

Comment: And you had a look at [**the actual browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture)!?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I should have read that section of the article before making the assumption that it is actually supported. They actually point that fact out.